# 'this' is not defined, Angular class not recognized. ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'newItem' of undefined, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angular, this

In the following Angular component I have two function, one of which returns a value of 'undefined' when I try to console.log(this), the other returns the value 'CartItemComponent'...as expected. I'm not getting any errors in terminal and am perplexed as to what the issue might be. I commented out the entire inside of the function and still the function returned a console.log(this) value of 'undefined'. Why might my function not recognize it's class?

```
export class CartItemComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() newItem: Product; // assigning data types from above data 
    model
    currentCart = this.cartService.get();


    constructor(private cartService: CartService) {}

    ngOnInit() {}


    addToCart() {
        const newCart = [];


        this.closeModal();
        alert('item(s) successfully added to cart');

        if (this.currentCart != null && this.currentCart.length > 0) {
            console.log('currentCart NOT empty, filter!');
            console.log('addToCart-->this:', this); //RETURNS 'CartItemComponent'
            this.cartService.set(this.currentCart.filter(this.removeDuplicates));

        } else { // if localStorage IS empty
            newCart.push(this.newItem); // pushes this.newItem;
            console.log('currentCart EMPTY, add this.newItem:', this.newItem);
            this.cartService.set(newCart); // pushes cart to localStorage;
        }
        this.cartService.get();
    }

    removeDuplicates(currentCart) {

        console.log('removeDuplicates()-->this:', this); //RETURNS 'undefined'
        const filteredCart = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < currentCart.length; i++) { // loop thru cart
            if (this.newItem.id !== currentCart[i].id) { // return all items that to not have a matching id
                filteredCart.push(currentCart[i]);
            }
        }
        filteredCart.push(this.newItem);
        console.log('filteredCart:', filteredCart, typeof filteredCart);
        return filteredCart;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because what `this` refers to inside a function depends on how the function is called (except for arrow functions).

Comment: @Robin As Felix mentioned, the binding for ‘this’ is set at invocation-time: can you show exactly how you are invoking each function?